# Ajax JSON Not Returning Data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am attempting to use jQuery/Ajax to call a PHP file returning all the required data in JSON format, however the page just gets stuck with the text "loading" at the bottom of the screen.
I have read various other posts on this but none have helped solve this issue for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'php/process.php',
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      $('.data').html(data['name']);
    }
  });
});
```

Simply including the PHP file in the page echoes the JSON with no problem, it's just calling it through jQuery/Ajax that isn't working for me.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'test', 'pass@word1', 'test');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test_json";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

$data = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($data, $row);
  }
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you look into the browsers console or into the browsers developer networking tool?

Comment: What is inside the `$data` after `json_encode` ?

Comment: Oh you're right. Turns out jQuery Mobile was throwing an error for something unrelated. Working now! Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding a header

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

right click and Inspect element.
Select the Network Tab
Select XHR at the bottom of the window
check the Response Header and the Response body.

Add

```
echo sql_error();
print_r($data);
```

From the Inspector I do not see a Request to "process.php"
I do see one to fetchposts()
fetchposts returns 3 line feeds and and a zero with a content length of 5 bytes

Comment: Inspect element showed an error in the console coming from jQuery Mobile which was completely unrelated. Fixed that and now it's working fine! But there is still a ReferenceError for data on the  that says line "data: data" - is it unnecessary to have this line?